# Is there a Switch to enable thousand digit grouping (100_000) by default in Iex

Tags: formatting, elixir, elixir-iex

Please is there a switch to enable thousand digit grouping (e.g `100_000`) by default in Iex. It would be really helpful if is.

Otherwise how can we specify it in `IO.puts`?

Comment: Not an answer but within iex type "h(Iex)" (minus the double quotes)--that will give you a lot more detail about what you can do in iex.  You can also type h(IO.puts).  I think the simple answer is there is no such switch in either case.

Comment: thanks, it is actually: h(IEx)

Comment: That's what I typed.

Comment: Actually no... h(Iex) will give errors, it's h(IEx) that works (at least on windows)

Comment: Oh--duh.  I follow you now.  If I could edit my comment I would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native option to enable digit grouping as you described according to [`Inspect.Opts`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Inspect.Opts.html).

However, the following should work to override the behavior of inspect when using `IEx` with `Integer` and `Float` if you place it in your local `~/.iex.exs` file:

```erlang
defmodule PrettyNumericInspect do
  def group(value, :binary, true),
    do: value |> group_by(8)
  def group(value, :decimal, true),
    do: value |> group_by(3)
  def group(value, :hex, true),
    do: value |> group_by(2)
  def group(value, :octal, true),
    do: value |> group_by(4)
  def group(value, _, _),
    do: value

  defp group_by(value, n) when byte_size(value) > n do
    size = byte_size(value)
    case size |> rem(n) do
      0 ->
        (for << << g :: binary-size(n) >> <- value >>,
          into: [],
          do: g)
        |> Enum.join("_")
      r ->
        {head, tail} = value |> String.split_at(r)
        [head, group_by(tail, n)] |> Enum.join("_")
    end
  end
  defp group_by(value, _),
    do: value
end

defimpl Inspect, for: Float do
  def inspect(thing, %Inspect.Opts{pretty: pretty}) do
    [head, tail] = IO.iodata_to_binary(:io_lib_format.fwrite_g(thing))
    |> String.split(".", parts: 2)
    [PrettyNumericInspect.group(head, :decimal, pretty), tail]
    |> Enum.join(".")
  end
end

defimpl Inspect, for: Integer do
  def inspect(thing, %Inspect.Opts{base: base, pretty: pretty}) do
    Integer.to_string(thing, base_to_value(base))
    |> PrettyNumericInspect.group(base, pretty)
    |> prepend_prefix(base)
  end

  defp base_to_value(base) do
    case base do
      :binary  -> 2
      :decimal -> 10
      :octal   -> 8
      :hex     -> 16
    end
  end

  defp prepend_prefix(value, :decimal), do: value
  defp prepend_prefix(value, base) do
    prefix = case base do
      :binary -> "0b"
      :octal  -> "0o"
      :hex    -> "0x"
    end
    prefix <> value
  end
end
```

The `Inspect.Opts` option `:pretty` must be set to `true` for the digit grouping to be displayed.  According to the documentation for [`IEx.configure/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/iex/IEx.html#configure/1) pretty inspect should be enabled by default.

When launching `iex`, you will see 2 warnings about redefining `Inspect.Float` and `Inspect.Integer`, but it should continue to work like normal afterwards:

```erlang
iex> 100_000
100_000
iex> 100_000.1
100_000.1
```

It also supports groupings for the different `:base` options (`:binary`, `:decimal`, `:octal`, and `:hex`):

```erlang
iex> inspect 0b11111111_11111111, base: :binary, pretty: true
"0b11111111_11111111"
iex> inspect 999_999, base: :decimal, pretty: true
"999_999"
iex> inspect 0o7777_7777, base: :octal, pretty: true
"0o7777_7777"
iex> inspect 0xFF_FF, base: :hex, pretty: true
"0xFF_FF"
```